# Function with guards: syntax error when using "where"

Tags: haskell, syntax

MWE:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

fibStep :: State (Integer, Integer) ()
fibStep = state $ \(a, b) -> ((), (b, a + b))

execStateN :: Int -> State s a -> s -> s
execStateN n m s
  | n == 1 = execState m s
  | n > 1 = let s' = execState m s in
              execStateN (n - 1) m s'
  -- | n > 1 = execStateN (n - 1) m s' where s' = execState m s
  | otherwise = error "undefined behaviour"
```

It works, but as soon as I uncomment `where` variant and comment the `let` one, it gives syntax error:

> error: parse error on input ‘|’

I checked the indents, they are fine. What's wrong?

Comment: The `where` is scoped over all guards, so you should put it at the end of the guards.

Comment: `execStateN n m s = execState (replicateM n m) s`

Comment: And just to note, if you change `fibStep` to `state $ (\a, b) -> (a, (b, a+b))`, then `evalState (replicateM n fibStep) (0, 1)` will give you a list of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @chepner "evalState (replicateM n fibStep) (0, 1) will give you a list of the first n Fibonacci numbers" - this is what it was intended to do. I eventually created almost the same function as you: `execStateN n m = execState $ replicateM_ n m` (s parameter omitted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `where` is scoped over all the guards, so you put it at the end of the guards, like:

```
execStateN :: Int -> State s a -> s -> s
execStateN n m s
  | n == 1 = execState m s
  | n > 1 = execStateN (n - 1) m s'
  | otherwise = error "undefined behaviour"
  where s' = execState m s
```